# c# windows service problem with memory (memory leak?)

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, timer

I have a little problem with memory management in a Windows Service written in C# (framework 3.5, visual studio 2008).

The service run fine, with a Timer and a CallBack the fire the procedure every 3 minutes.
Therefore, the memory in the Windows Task Manager slowly growing at every timer's run.

Have you an idea to how resolve this issue?

To simplify the problem, below is a very simple code that exibits the same problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace svcTest
{
public partial class svcTest : ServiceBase
{

    private Timer tmr;
    private TimerCallback tmrCallBack;

    public svcTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("Service Started on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
        m_streamWriter.Close();

        tmrCallBack = new TimerCallback(goEXE);
        tmr = new Timer(tmrCallBack, null, 0, 1000 * 60 * 1 / 2);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("Service Stopped on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
        m_streamWriter.Close();

        tmr.Dispose();
    }

    private void goEXE(Object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("Service running on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
        m_streamWriter.Close();

    }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

stefano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not disposing your `FileStream`.  The garbage collector can call `Dispose()` for you, but it's non-deterministic (i.e. you don't know when/if it's going to happen).  It's probably decided here not to bother.  As a result, recommended best practice is to consider wrapping anything that implements `IDisposable` in `using` statements:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
{
    using (using (StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs)))
    {
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("Service Started on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
    }
}
```

For maintenance and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) reasons, you should also consider refactoring the file-writing code to a separate method:

```
private void Log(string message)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
    {
        using (using (StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs)))
        {
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(message + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Log("Service Started");

    tmrCallBack = new TimerCallback(goEXE);
    tmr = new Timer(tmrCallBack, null, 0, 1000 * 60 * 1 / 2);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    Log("Service Stopped");

    tmr.Dispose();
}

private void goEXE(Object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

    Log("Service running");
}
```

Comment: private void goEXE(Object state)
        {

             ... same code as above ...
            m_streamWriter.Dispose();
            fs.Dispose();
        }

Comment: Nice just fixed an memory leak using a StreamWriter! Thx!

Comment: Why the nested using on the StreamWriter? I searched around but don't see an answer.

Comment: Simply because it implements `IDisposable` disposing disposable objects is best practice.

Comment: You could make it a private field or something and keep it around, only disposing of it when the parent object is itself disposed, but that wasn't really the point of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, .NET's Garbage Collection runs when certain optimal parameters are hit. If the system isn't running low on memory, it may decide that running a GC.Collect is too expensive, and thus your non-referenced, but still in memory objects will continue to stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your file keeps growing since you're appending new lines
to the end and thus streamwriter is consuming more memory.

I would rather create one stream writer at programm start up
instead of doing it at the callback. But then you will have a file locked
by your service.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Logger : IDisposable
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\svclog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        {
            using (using (StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs)))
            {
                m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                m_streamWriter.WriteLine(message + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" *----------------*");
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.AppendAllText(path, content);` it is best, it will handle all your memory leaks.